# flex grid not working for p-col-# primeng Angular 5

Tags: angular, primeng

i am using primeNG for angular

https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/flexgrid

when i am trying this

```
<div class="p-grid">
<div class="p-col-6">
<div class="box">6 </div>
</div>
<div class="p-col-6">
<div class="box">6 </div>
</div>

</div>
```

the boxs are on top of each other and not next to each other 
i run

```
npm install primeflex --save
```

and added

```
"node_modules/primeflex/primeflex.css"
```

to angular.json

seems to be some thing related to the primeflex.css

the p-col class is working fine but the p-col-# (p-col-1 , p-col-2 etc ) are not working as excpected

this is the values for the p-col

```
-webkit-box-flex: 1;
-ms-flex-positive: 1;
flex-grow: 1;
-ms-flex-preferred-size: 0;
flex-basis: 0;
padding: 0.5em;
```

this is the values for the p-col-#

```
-webkit-box-flex: 0;
-ms-flex: 0 0 auto;
flex: 0 0 auto;
padding: 0.5em;
```

if for exmample i change the padding of the p-col-# to 0 then it is working but i don't have padding..
(i tried to change the p-col-# to the same values as the p-col and it is not working )

any ideas ?

Thanks 
Rahav

Comment: First time I implemented primeflex followed the steps given by you. It is working perfectly.  Whenever you make any changes in angular.json you should restart the app to apply the changes. I used angular v6, primeng v6 and cli v6 and node vs 8. For reference check my git here  [git](https://github.com/alokkarma/angular6-primeNg/blob/development/src/app/about/about.component.html)

Comment: for me it is not working , i run  npm update --save to update to lastest version Angular CLI: 6.2.2 , Node: 8.9.3 ,Angular: 6.1.7 ,   "primeng": "^6.1.3",  "primeflex": "^1.0.0-rc.1",  but it is still not working

Comment: i had same issue with primeflex version 3, it worked on changing same with version 2

Answer (score 18):

It is work in my Angular6 project.

1. install PrimeNG and PrimeFlex

   ```
   npm install primeng --save
   npm install primeflex --save
   ```
2. add style to angular.json

   ```
   "./node_modules/primeng/resources/primeng.css",
   "./node_modules/primeflex/primeflex.css"
   ```

app.component.html

```
<div class="p-grid">
    <div class="p-col">1</div>
    <div class="p-col">2</div>
    <div class="p-col">3</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 13):

use "grid" instead of "p-grid", there is class
name change in lib files.

Comment: I can confirm, it looks like removing the "p-" prefix is the solution  with the following versions 

 "primeflex": "^3.0.1",
  "primeicons": "^4.1.0",
  "primeng": "^12.1.0-rc.1",

Comment: This worked for me as well, though I had to also change the nested "p-col" classes to "col".

Comment: yes they toke all p-* https://github.com/primefaces/primeflex/compare/2.0.0-rc.1...master . for me i was using old version of primeng which cause incompatibility issue

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem in Angular 7 with PrimeNG PrimeFlex.

Added the following to the styles.css file to fix it.

```
 * {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

For PrimeNG version 3 or more use "grid" instead of "p-grid" and "col" instead of "p-col".

No need to update any library.

Note - Stack - Angular 12 and PrimeNG 3.X.X

Comment: It seems to explain same informations as most upvoted answers

Answer (score 1):

1. install PrimeNG and PrimeFlex

   ```
   npm install primeng --save

   npm i primeflex@2.0.0 --save
   ```
2. add style to angular.json

   ```
   "./node_modules/primeng/resources/primeng.css",

   "./node_modules/primeflex/primeflex.css"
   ```

**Please use primeflex 2.0.0 , Latest version (3+) have some issues.**

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the other answers about removing the `p-` from `grid` and `col` in PrimeNG PrimeFlex version 3, I had to go through the source code to find that the breakpoints have also changed to a new syntax.

Old: `p-sm-6`
New: `sm:col-8`

Example:

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="col-12 sm:col-10 md:col-8 lg:col-6 xl:col-4">
    <!-- Column content -->
  <div>
</div>
```